# Unit test redis library node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, redis, jestjs

I am trying to perform a unit test but the test does not enter the client.hgetall method of the "Redis" library, is it possible to mock that function?

```
const {createClient} = require('redis');
const client = createClient(redisOptions);

const authorizeRequest = (requestToken, requestPath, requestMethod, requestParams, callback) => {
    client.hgetall(decoded.payload.id, (error, response) => {
        if (error){
            logger.log("error consultando", error);
            callback(responseMessages.INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }
        if (!response) {
            logger.log("respuesta consulta :",response);
            callback(responseMessages.NOT_FOUND );
        }
        else{
            logger.log("response from redis", response);
            const areLast = isTheLast(response.sid,decoded.payload.sid)
        }
        client.quit();
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? And show the test result.

Comment: Have you tried to use *redis-mock* library? There is support for *hgetall* method.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-mock